# How would you make a table of buttons, but no gaps in between the buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, html-table

I am working on a website, and realised, I don't know how to make no gaps in between the buttons. I took to the internet, but I can't form what I want into words. I want to make a table, but there be no gaps in between the buttons I put in the table.

If you can help, I would like the code to be restricted to html, CSS, and Javascript.

Comment: Can you demonstrate for us what it is you've coded so far?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Shilly I have that, there is still a gap though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys to getting there were the combination of border-collapse and a css reset for margin and padding.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1.1</td>
      <td>Cell 1.2</td>
      <td>Cell 1.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 2.1</td>
      <td>Cell 2.2</td>
      <td>Cell 2.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 3.1</td>
      <td>Cell 3.2</td>
      <td>Cell 3.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>Button 4.1</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>Button 4.2</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>Button 4.3</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>Button 5.1</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>Button 5.2</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>Button 5.3</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow shilly, thanks for taking the time to write that. That helped alot.